# How to get HttpServletRequest information from UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm working with spring security and I have implemented my costume UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername that returns a costume UserDetails. My problem is that I want in my UserDetailsService  implementation to get information from the HttpServletRequest, more specific I would like to get `request.getLocale();` How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able (depending on your config) to use

```
LocaleContextHolder.getLocaleContext().getLocale();
```

`LocaleContextHolder` stores a `static` `ThreadLocal` object that stores the `Locale` for your request.

You might have to register a `RequestContextListener` with your Servlet container.

Comment: OK, i tried it and LocaleContextHolder.getLocaleContext().getLocale(); return null but LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(); works. im trying to understand whats the difference between them? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html

Comment: @lior That's surprising because the `DispatcherServlet` should set the `LocaleContext` in its `initContextHolders()` method. You seem to be using Spring 3.1.4. I'm on 3.2+. Maybe that's the difference. Implementation change in more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it from the controller to your Service , adding a new parameter to your Service

Comment: The UserDetailsService is called during the spring security authentication. how can pass it to it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this for others as I could not find the answer elsewhere.
After some tinkering, I found that you can just add the request to the bean as such:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(MyRepository repository, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return username -> {
            UserDetails userDetails = repository.findByEmail(username);
            if (userDetails != null) {
                log.info("login." + userDetails);
                return userDetails;
            }
            String locale = request.getLocale().getDisplayName();
            String message = "not.found[" + username + "].locale[" + locale + "]";
            log.error(message);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(message);
        };
    }
}
```